# How does the concept of a random variable come into play when sampling?

Tags: sampling, random-variable

I have an (intuitive) understanding of what a random variable and a sample are. However, I am not sure how a random variable is related to a sample.

Suppose we have a population of people. Sampling from that population means to take a subset (which we call "sample") of those people.

What can be considered a random variable while sampling, once we have a sample and when we take an element from this sample? **How many** random variables are involved in the process of sampling or once we have the sample?

I would appreciate seeing many real-world examples of the sampling process where you explain which and **how many** random variables are involved.

---

**Notes**

<sub>1. This question is different from [What is the difference between random variable and random sample?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/239500/82135).</sub>

<sub>2. Please, avoid defining what a random variable and sample are. I already know what they are and, if I forget the definitions, I can look them up again!</sub>

Comment: Tell us how you count random variables and then we can tell you the answer!  For instance, when sampling tickets from a box, suppose each ticket has two values written on it, labeled $X_1$ and $X_2$.  From your perspective, would that be two random variables or a *single* random variable $(X_1,X_2)$?

Comment: Despite your request to not define random variables, your question and your comments suggest you do not have the same understanding of a random variable as many others do.  It might help to state what you believe it to be.

Comment: You give a mathematical definition, but the concern in your question is how the mathematics is used to *model* sampling.  Your comment about being unsure about "model[ing] each ticket as an r.v." is inconsistent with a correct application of the math.  The tickets model the outcomes; the measurable function writes numbers on the tickets.  Thus, values on the tickets are the opposite of "not important": they are *crucial.* The sampling process consists of pulling a ticket out of the box.

Comment: Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50/what-is-meant-by-a-random-variable/54894#54894.

Answer (score 1):

There are two major ways of approaching random sampling. One is parametric, assuming that each unit responds based on a function of their characteristics plus an error. This error is the random variable that @Robien1 describes.

The other method treats the responses received from units in the population as fixed constants. The random variable in this case is a 0/1 indicator variable for each unit in the population, indicating whether the unit is selected in the sample or not.

In survey analysis the first method is called the model-based, the second is called the design-based or model-assisted. The design-based method is useful if you have access to (or can build) a population frame.

Answer (score 0):

Let us take a  human population of $N$ persons. 
Among that population $N_0$ persons have blue eyes and let's call $p=\dfrac{N_0}{N}$ the proportion of blue-eyes persons.

If you pick « randomly » somebody in that population and associate the value 1 if that person has blue eyes and 0 otherwise, you are constructing a real random variable $X$ because il has uncertain issue.

To make it simple $X$ takes two values and $P(X=1)=p$, $P(X=0)=1-p$ ($P$ being  a measure of probability, the existence/construction of such  a probability is a big step, not necessary here, where the intuition makes it understable/acceptable).

For your sample, the $i$-th person picked is associated with a random variable $X_i$. All the $X_i$ follow the same law (of probability) called $B(p)$ (Bernoulli) : 1 with probability $p$, 0 with probability $1-p$).

So if you have a $n$-sample, you have a $n$ random variables associated
and what you handle in your real sample are issues of that variables: $X_1(\omega)=0$,
$X_2(\omega)=1$,
$\dots$,
$X_n(\omega)=0$ (for example)

Then the theory of probabilities give you some information
like $\dfrac{\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i}{n}\to p$ in a sense
if the variables are independant which in that case would be picking 
each time a new personn in the whole population, otherwise they are dependant
but if the $n$-sample  picked is small in comparison with $N$ then you can approximate with independance.

To finish you get :
$x_1,\dots x_n$ in your sample
and the probability model consider it as
$X_1(\omega),X_2(\omega),\dots,X_n(\omega)$
where the $X_i$ follow the same law of probability and are most of the time mutually independants (or so-approximated)

I hope it answers your question.

Comment: Yes by issue i mean realizations (pb of translation) and when i say what you handle,it is the set of values observed, here it would be 0,1,1,0,0,0 or 180,200,196,... if you get weights for example

Comment: each choice of element of your sample is made independantly of the others, the results are thus independant and each is associated with a RV. You can associate a RV to the whole sample but it is of the form $(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n)$ a $n$-uple of real RV, it doesn't change anything. You have result

Comment: Typically when we sample the unit selections are not independent. If they were independent then you could select the same unit more than once.